# Flask WTForm from list of field labels

Tags: flask, dynamic, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to create a dynamic form from a given list of labels using Flask, WTForms and Jinja2.
The form should contain a `StringField` for every given label.
My current approach is to use a `FieldList` like in the code below.

My problem with this approach is, that I can't distinguish between the keys in the dictionary of each request.

`request.form` gives me this `ImmutableMultiDict([('text', ''), ('text', ''), ('submit', 'submit')])` with key duplicates.

How can I find out which value was entered into which `StringField`?

Ideally `request.form` should look like this `ImmutableMultiDict([('field 1', ''), ('field 2', ''), ('submit', 'submit')])`.

### Front end (index.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% for entry in form.entries %}
                <p>{{entry.text.label}}: {{ entry.text }}</p> 
            {% endfor %}
            <p>{{form.submit()}}</p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Back end

```py
from wtforms import FieldList, FormField, StringField, SubmitField
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm


class TextForm(FlaskForm):
    text = StringField('Placeholder')

class TextListForm(FlaskForm):
    entries = FieldList(FormField(TextForm))
    submit = SubmitField(u'submit')


from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    SECRET_KEY = 'asdf',
)
field_names = ["field 1", "field 2"]


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    fields = []
    for name in field_names:
        text_entry = TextForm()
        text_entry.text.label = name
        fields.append(text_entry)

    form = TextListForm()
    form.entries = fields

    if form.is_submitted():
        print(request.form)

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Output: `ImmutableMultiDict([('text', ''), ('text', ''), ('submit', 'submit')])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot to set the field name: `text_entry.text.name = name`

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    fields = []
    for name in field_names:
        text_entry = TextForm()
        text_entry.text.label = name
        text_entry.text.name = name
        fields.append(text_entry)

    form = TextListForm()
    form.entries = fields

    if form.is_submitted():
        print(request.form)

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Now the desired dict is returned: `ImmutableMultiDict([('field 1', ''), ('field 2', ''), ('submit', 'submit')])`